# AWS Lambda function fails while query Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I am attempting to write a simple Lambda function to query a table in Athena. But after a few seconds I see "Status: FAILED" in the Cloudwatch logs.
There is no descriptive error message on the cause of failure.

My test code is below:

```
import json
import time
import boto3

# athena constant
DATABASE = 'default'
TABLE = 'test'

# S3 constant
S3_OUTPUT = 's3://test-output/'

# number of retries
RETRY_COUNT = 1000

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # created query
    query = "SELECT * FROM default.test limit 2"
    #  % (DATABASE, TABLE)
    # athena client
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    
    # Execution
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': DATABASE
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': S3_OUTPUT,
        }
    )
    
    # get query execution id
    query_execution_id = response['QueryExecutionId']
    print(query_execution_id)
    
    # get execution status
    for i in range(1, 1 + RETRY_COUNT):

        # get query execution
        query_status = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id)
        query_execution_status = query_status['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']

        if query_execution_status == 'SUCCEEDED':
            print("STATUS:" + query_execution_status)
            break

        if query_execution_status == 'FAILED':
            #raise Exception("STATUS:" + query_execution_status)
            print("STATUS:" + query_execution_status)

        else:
            print("STATUS:" + query_execution_status)
            time.sleep(i)
    else:
        # Did not encounter a break event. Need to kill the query
        client.stop_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id)
        raise Exception('TIME OVER')
        
    # get query results
    result = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id)
    print(result)
    return
```

The logs show the following:

```
2020-08-31T10:52:12.443-04:00
    
START RequestId: e5434651-d36e-48f0-8f27-0290 Version: $LATEST
    
2020-08-31T10:52:13.481-04:00
    
88162f38-bfcb-40ae-b4a3-0b5a21846e28
    
2020-08-31T10:52:13.500-04:00
    
STATUS:QUEUED
    
2020-08-31T10:52:14.519-04:00
    
STATUS:RUNNING
    
2020-08-31T10:52:16.540-04:00
    
STATUS:RUNNING
    
2020-08-31T10:52:19.556-04:00
    
STATUS:RUNNING
    
2020-08-31T10:52:23.574-04:00
    
STATUS:RUNNING
    
2020-08-31T10:52:28.594-04:00
    
STATUS:FAILED
    
2020-08-31T10:52:28.640-04:00
    
....more status: FAILED
....
    
END RequestId: e5434651-d36e-48f0-8f27-0290
    
REPORT RequestId: e5434651-d36e-48f0-8f27-0290 Duration: 30030.22 ms Billed Duration: 30000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 72 MB Init Duration: 307.49 ms

2020-08-31T14:52:42.473Z e5434651-d36e-48f0-8f27-0290 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
```

I think I have the right permissions for S3 bucket access given to the role (if not, I would have seen the error message). There are no files created in the bucket either. I am not sure what is going wrong here. What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: If you run the query in the Amazon Athena console, how long does it take to run?

Comment: to test you first need to make sure that this query works fine in Athena directly ? Can you run this in Athena and confirm?]\

Comment: It's your code that prints FAILED, try printing more of the error you get back from Athena.

Answer (score 2):

The last line in your log shows

```
2020-08-31T14:52:42.473Z e5434651-d36e-48f0-8f27-0290 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
```

To me this looks like the timeout of the Lambda Function is set to 30 seconds. Try increasing it to more than the time the Athena query needs (the maximum is 15 minutes).

Comment: I increased the timeout to 10 minutes. But I get STATUS:FAILED. Not sure if something wrong in the way the query is constructed. Unable to get info on why the function fails.

Comment: Two thing you can do for further investigations
1. Try the query in the AWS Console and see if errors arise or 2. Also print "StateChangeReason" and the "ErrorMessage" field from "UnprocessedQueryExecutionIds" section to see further error messages (see response syntax [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_execution))